# The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, keystore, keytool

I am trying desperately to automate an install process for a program I work with.  One of the pieces of the process involves editing a keystore file to remove a key pair, and I've verified that keytool works great with this.  I wrote two PowerShell scripts.  The first edits all the Windows settings, installs all the required server roles/features, and creates a scheduled task to run the second Powershell script on logon after the next reboot.

The second script runs the *.exe file for the application I'm installing, then edits the registry to make sure javahome points to the proper location, and then it attempts to edit the keystore with:

```
keytool -delete -noprompt -alias *.network.internal -Keystore $keystore -Storepass $mypwd
```

When I run the script I get:

```
keytool : The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Path\Script.ps1:150 char:13
+             keytool -delete -noprompt -alias *.network.inter ...
+             ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (keytool:String) [], CommandNotFoundException                                 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Just for grins, I opened up PowerShell and just ran the line by itself, and it worked without issue.  I then decided to try to separate the second script out into two scripts.  One to run the installer, and another to handle the certificates.  I then created a bat file to call each script up separately.  I got the same error.  Then I ran each of the two scripts separately and it worked without issue.

I'm curious if anyone has any thoughts on what my problem might be here.  I can post my entire code if necessary, but it's going to take a while to change the names to protect the guilty.

Edit:  Here is a stripped down version of my code

```
#Mount ISO to next available drive letter
    $availableDrive = (68..90 | %{$L=[char]$_; if ((gdr).Name -notContains $L) {$L}})[0]
    $driveLetter = "${availableDrive}:\"
    $diskImg = Mount-DiskImage "C:\Software\Application.ISO" -NoDriveLetter -PassThru
    $volInfo = $diskImg | Get-Volume
    mountvol $driveLetter $volInfo.UniqueId

#Install *.exe from newly mounted drive
    $InstallerFolder = "${availableDrive}:\Software"
    Invoke-Expression -Command "$InstallerFolder\Application.exe"
    Pause

#Update registry to set javahome
    $regFilePath = "C:\Software\Support Tools\KeyStore Explorer"
    regedit.exe /S $regFilePath\Set_Java_Path_for_KSE.reg

#Backup Keystore File

    Copy-Item D:\Folder\Application.keystore -Destination D:\Folder\Application.keystore.bak

#Edit keystore to delete *.network.internal
    keytool -delete -noprompt -alias *.network.internal -Keystore D:\Folder\Application.keystore -Storepass Password123

Write-host "done"
Pause
```

It throws the keytool error the first time I run it.  If I run it a second time, it notifies me that the Application.exe is already installed, but the keytool command runs without issue.

Comment: It sounds like the `$env:PATH` entry for `keytool`'s directory may be defined at the _user_  rather than the _machine_ (system) level. Thus, if you run with a different user identity, such as `SYSTEM` via a scheduled task, that entry won't be present.

Comment: Possibly... But I've also tried just running without the scheduled task and still get the same thing when I run everything all at once.

Comment: @mklement0 - I've edited my post with my stripped down code.  The error happens whether I run it via the scheduled task, or if I run it manually.

Comment: Easiest way to test is to provide the full filepath for keytool e.g. `c:\folder\keytool.exe` rather than relying on it being in the system/java path.

Comment: I did that as well.  Same thing.  It only works after I've run this script once.  If I run it a second time it works.  If I break it up into two scripts and use a single bat file to execute them both , I get an error.  If I use a bat file to run the first script (right through the ````regedit.exe /S $regFilePath\Set_Java_Path_for_KSE.reg```` line, then a second bat file to run the remainder in a separate script, it works.  I think it has to be something to do with either installing the original exe or mounting the ISO file that is causing the problem.

Comment: So is `keytool.exe` located on the newly mounted drive? Where is its directory added to `$env:PATH`? As aside: better to use `& "$InstallerFolder\Application.exe"` than `Invoke-Expression -Command "$InstallerFolder\Application.exe"`

Comment: No, the only thing on the newly mounted drive is the ISO containing the exe for the app installer.  The app gets installed to the C drive, and keytool.exe is located in ````C:\Program FIles\MyApp\jre\bin````

Comment: Alright, so in the end, I was informed the only reason we needed to restart the server was due to disabling the UAC.  So I switched it to run the installer in my first script, then reboot and do everything with keytool, and that is now working without issue.  Still not sure why I couldn't install the application and run keytool in the same script, but I'm still able to accomplish everything with exactly as much input as I intended.